# Config Profile ~/.bash and ~/.bash_profile Default & Preferred Permissions?

Tags: bash, permission, configuration-profiles

On MacOS, what are the default and preferred permissions for `~/.bash` and `~/.bash_profile` config profiles?

[This guide](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/) shows 700 as preferred.

To view permission for a file: `private stat -f "%Lp %N" ~/.bashrc`

[Permissions guide](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html).

Comment: There is no `private` command, just run `ls -l ~/.bashrc` to see permissions. Also, what is the purpose of the „Permissions Guide“ link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bashrc` and `bash_profile` are read by `bash` and do not require the execute bit to be set. Nor do either require the execute bit set when sourcing the file in your current bash session. That said, an octal representation of `600` would be my choice.

The default permissions set on a file is governed by `umask`.